# Menu icon in actionbar not showing

Tags: android

In my Android app, I show the actionbar and normally in the far left is my app's logo and to the left of the logo is the icon that lets you display the navigation drawer. This icon is typically 3 horizontally bars above each other.

After modifying my app, this menu icon is no longer visible. Instead, an arrow for "back" is now displayed.

I even have:

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

This gets rid of the arrow for navigating Up (or back) but the 3 bar menu item never shows. I still can press on my app's logo to the right and it will bring up the navigation drawer.

What is preventing the menu icon from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have this problem and it was when I used a Fragment instead of an Activity. When you use an activity, you got the three lines to open the menu (if of course you enabled it), if you have a fragment, then you have an arrow.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I'm using a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use this :

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        )
```

Where the ic_drawer is the 3 bars icons. [I use this tutorial to create my app Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

**Hopefully this can help you anyhow =)**

Comment: That's what I'm using. Seems to be something else is causing it to disappear.

Comment: Could you show us you "onOptionsItemSelected" function please ?